# Does a characteristic function in the format $e^{v^{T}Kv}$ implies a random vector with a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions, gaussian

I know that if I have a Gaussian random vector $X$ with mean $m_X$=$[0]$, then I have a characteristic function $M_x(v)=e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}v^{T}Kv}$. In the other hand, if I have a characteristic function $M_x(v)=e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}v^{T}Kv}$ and a known mean $m_X$=$[0]$, then I can say $X$ is a Gaussian random vector. But if I only have the characteristic function $M_x(v)=e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}v^{T}Kv}$, can I say both $X$ is a Gaussian vector and it has mean $m_X$=$[0]$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae

Comment: @d.k.o., it did not help...

Comment: Given the characteristic function you can compute all moments. The mean is a moment.

Comment: @user619894, it makes sense... but I'm still wondering how to do it. I can find the joint fdp for $X$ (let's suppose $X= [X_1 X_2]^T$ ) using Fourier inverse transform. But then I stuck trying to find $E[ X_1 X_2]$.

Comment: @d.k.o. may have been overspecific, but a few minutes reading about the characteristic function will be of great use.

Comment: From @user619894 comment, I finally got it. First, finding the pdf of $X$ gives me $p_X(x_1,x_2) = \dfrac{e^{-x_1^2+x_1x_2-x_2^2}}{2\pi\sqrt{3}}$. Then, $E[X_1] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_1\dfrac{e^{-x_1^2+x_1x_2-x_2^2}}{2\pi\sqrt{3}}\,dx\,dy = 0$ (similarly, $E[X_2]=0$). So, yes, $M_x(v) = e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}v^Tkv}$ implies the random vector $X$ is Gaussian with mean $m_X=[0]$.